# C++ to Delphi dll call

Tags: c, delphi, dll

I am trying to convert this code to delphi 7

```
LIBEXPORT int __stdcall MY_GetDLLInfo(const char **pp_version, const char **pp_release_type, const char **pp_build_date, const char **pp_load_path);

// C++ Call Example

const char *p_version      = NULL;
const char *p_release_type = NULL;
const char *p_build_date   = NULL;

MY_GetDLLInfo(&p_version,&p_release_type,&p_build_date,NULL);
```

Delphi Code

```
MY_GetDLLInfo: function (const pp_version:PPAnsiChar;const pp_release_type:PPAnsiChar;const pp_build_date:PPAnsiChar;const pp_load_path:PPAnsiChar): Integer; stdcall;

// Delphi Call Example

var
  hHandle:THandle;
  p_version,p_release_type,p_build_date,p_load_path:PPAnsiChar;
begin
  hHandle := LoadLibrary(Dl_path);
    @MY_GetDLLInfo:=GetProcAddress(hHandle, PChar('MY_GetDLLInfo'));

    if Assigned(MY_GetDLLInfo) then begin
     MY_GetDLLInfo(p_version,p_release_type,p_build_date,@null);

     ShowMessage(StrPas(@p_version)); // <- I Get Strange Output 
     ShowMessage(StrPas(@p_release_type)); // <- I Get Strange Output 
     ShowMessage(StrPas(@p_build_date)); // <- I Get Strange Output 
    end;

end;
```

With my converted code i get strange output 
I think i am doing wrong at using strpas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char*` in C/C++ is `PAnsiChar` in Delphi, and `char**` is `PPAnsiChar`.

Your local string variables need to be declared as `PAnsiChar`, not as `PPAnsiChar`, and then you need to use the `@` address operator (Delphi's equivilent of C/C++'s `&` address operator) to pass the variables into the function.

Also, `null` is a `Variant` in Delphi.  To assign a null to a pointer, you need to use `nil` instead.

Try this:

```pascal
// Delphi Call Example

var
  hHandle: THandle;
  MY_GetDLLInfo: function(const pp_version, pp_release_type, pp_build_date, pp_load_path: PPAnsiChar): Integer; stdcall;
  p_version, p_release_type, p_build_date: PAnsiChar;
begin
  hHandle := LoadLibrary(Dl_path);
  if hHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    @MY_GetDLLInfo := GetProcAddress(hHandle, 'MY_GetDLLInfo');
    if Assigned(MY_GetDLLInfo) then
    begin
      p_version := nil;
      p_release_type := nil;
      p_build_date := nil;

      MY_GetDLLInfo(@p_version, @p_release_type, @p_build_date, nil);

      ShowMessage(p_version);
      ShowMessage(p_release_type);
      ShowMessage(p_build_date);
    end;

    FreeLibrary(hHandle);
  end;
end;
```